# Git restore files locally deleted not committed yet

Tags: git

I’m new to Git and accidentally deleted all my physical local files on my desktop and library. Due to initiating git from wrong directory.  I have not committed it yet. How do I restore the files back?

The current git status is:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   .DS_Store
    new file:   .gitconfig
    new file:   Desktop/.DS_Store
```

Now:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   .DS_Store
    new file:   .gitconfig
    new file:   Desktop/.DS_Store
```

How do you get the local files back?

The deleted files represent more than 1.5gb. I don't want to commit them or push them to remote if they are in staging area. But I need to restore the files on the local desktop.

Comment: If the files weren't being tracked by Git (they weren't added or committed yet), what does Git have to do with this at all, and what makes you think Git can magically restore your files?

Comment: I haven't committed them yet, I'm beginner with git. I accidentally deleted through git but haven't committed yet.

Comment: Like I said, if they weren't yet being tracked by Git, then this question has nothing to do with Git. At all.

Comment: If you added them to git (put them in the staging area / index) then you may get parts of them back (all changes made after you added them will be lost).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the files you deleted had not been tracked by Git you will not be able to use Git to get them back.

[This article](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository) talks about tracking files.

In the future, it's a good idea to commit early since even if you commit too frequently you can combine (*squash*) commits together before pushing them to a public repository.

EDIT: Per your comments it seems that after some Git operations you lost files that were already tracked by Git (meaning that they were added to a previous commit).

It also looks like the operation you performed put you in "detached HEAD" mode which means that your HEAD (where you are in the Git tree) is not pointed to by a branch.

So, probably it would be best to simply get back to the branch you were previously on. Let's say you were on the `master` branch. Run this command:

```
git checkout master
```

Then do a `git status` and make sure everything looks as it did prior to the faulty Git operations you performed.

Comment: I have lost all files on my local desktop, I don't know what exact steps I need to follow to get my files and folders back. Could you please guide me or show me the way.

Comment: @Lewan the point of my answer is that if those files had not yet been added to Git, then using Git you will not be able to get them back

Comment: The files I want to restore is in the staging area

Comment: HEAD detached at head
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

 new file:   .bash_history
 new file:   .bash_sessions/2BD34A0A-FD01-4C4C-9527-28209E47A6E4.historynew
 new file:   Desktop/.DS_Store
 new file:   Desktop/Vick/.DS_Store
 new file:   Desktop/vick/Luciopa

Comment: @Lewan I'm confused now... the files that you want to restore are the files listed as "new file"? And those results you listed are from a "git status" _after_ the deletions?

Comment: @Lewan that is confusing because that would indicate that the files are not deleted...

Comment: Yes exactly, It got deleted while performing git operations. But I have not committed the changes and now I did a reset and added them back. So should I commit now to have them back on my local desktop ?

Comment: the files are no more present on my local desktop and it only shows in the git status they are. how to I restore them

Comment: I did the hard reset and this is the status now, 
HEAD detached at head
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

 Desktop/
 Library/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Comment: @Lewan my sincere apologies...I meant to type the command "git checkout master". If Git gives an error during that do this: "git checkout .; git clean -fd; git checkout master"

Comment: Switched to branch 'master'

Status:
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

 Desktop/
 Library/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Comment: @Lewan, ok cool...so if those "untracked" files are the files you want do "git add ." and "git commit -m "my message" and you should be all set

Comment: Yes these are my files. I don't want to add them to remote but I want them to be restored locally.

Comment: @Lewan Great, you may want to stick them on a separate branch if you don't want to push them remotely. If you get stuck on that please open a new question

Comment: can I push them locally not on remote though

Comment: @Lewan nothing will be pushed until your run the "push" command. Commits are local

Comment: @Lewan, don't forget to mark this as the answer to your question. Jonathan certainly put in the leg work for this one!

Comment: @DavidDeutsch Danke David, Ich will :)

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink The total files which have got deleted physically is more than 1.5gb. I don't want to commit them or push them to remote if they are in staging area. But I need to restore the files physically on the local desktop.